# Cloud build angular npm run throws package.json error

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to build and deploy angular app via Cloud build and source code is in Source Repository. This is my yaml

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
args:
- install
id: Install angular
entrypoint: yarn
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
args:
- run
- build
- '--prod'
id: Create build
entrypoint: yarn
```

I tried earlier entrypoint as npm as well. Everytime I run this I get error

```
BUILD

Starting Step #0 - "Install angular"
Step #0 - "Install angular": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
Step #0 - "Install angular": yarn install v1.22.5
Step #0 - "Install angular": success Saved lockfile.
Step #1 - "Create build": error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/workspace"
Step #1 - "Create build": info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Finished Step #1 - "Create build"

ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/workspace"
```

My Angular code has package.json but at depth 2 (not sure if this info is needed). How can this error be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Cloud Build cannot find that `package.json` file *because* it isn't in the root. You can provide your npm script step with a [`dir` field](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema) so that `npm run` will run where your package file is.

For example, if your package file was in a `/src` directory, you'd want your step to be:

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['run', 'build']
  dir: 'src'
```

Comment: I added that as well , then it says /workspace/,<dir>/package.json not found

Comment: Interesting, are you using build triggers or are you using `gcloud builds submit`?

Comment: No not using that. Okay i changed cloudbuild to use npm instead of yarn and now error is
Step #2: Node.js version v14.10.1 detected.
Step #2: The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v12.20, v14.15, or v16.10.
Why is node 14.10 getting installed, shouldnt it install latest node 16 or so?

Comment: Okay, yeah as of Feb 15th '22 the [`gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm` cloud builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/npm) uses npm v14.10. In fact, it seems Google recommends using the `node` builder instead, which has multiple tagged versions with newer versions of `npm` available. For example, you could use `name: node:16` with `entrypoint: npm` to get the latest version of Node 16.

Comment: its finally working, but i really dont know why this node 16 didnt work earlier. GCP seems to be temperamental too because it is sometimes executing in more than 10 mins giving timeout error and sometime just within 2 mins. Or maybe its aligning with time zone of my region. Thanks @tanner-stern